# How do you generate a blob URL?

Tags: vue.js, blob

I'm trying to set the `img` `src` to a blob URL in vuejs.

I have tried to call `loadImg()` method inside `img` `src`; and It didn't work. Here is my code:

```
<template>
 <a v-for="(post,index) in posts" :key="index">
     <img :src="loadImg(post.img)" >
 </a>
</template>

methods:{

loadImg: function (img) {

        fetch(img)
         .then(function(t){return t.blob()})
         .then(function(e){
          return URL.createObjectURL(e);
        }
      )
 }

}
```

How do I set the image `src` to blob url?
codesandbox => https://codesandbox.io/embed/2vmwj2k550

Comment: Hmm.. For images, I think the standard practice is to convert it to a Data URL rather than Blob. Do let me know if you want me to give you the answer for that instead?

Comment: 1) Don't use methods to return content in your templates. 2) Your method doesn't return anything. 3) Your method is asynchronous so at best, you could return a `Promise` which won't render anything in your template

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/2vmwj2k550

Comment: @Phil whats is the correct way to set image src to a blob url here is codesandbox link,
 https://codesandbox.io/embed/2vmwj2k550

Comment: Where does `posts` come from?

Comment: data () {
      return {
posts: [
        { title: "post1", img: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
        { title: "post2", img: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" }
      ],
 }
},

Comment: this.posts array is hard coded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you really don't want to use a method here. For one, they are highly inefficient when used to inject content.

What you want to do instead is load the images asynchronously and handle the various states.

For example

```js
data () {
  return { posts: [/* your data goes here */] } // initial data
},
async created () {
  for (let post of posts) { // using for..of so async actually waits
    // create some nice placeholder images to show something while they load
    // including the placeholder would probably work better in your initial data
    this.$set(post, 'imgUrl', 'some-nice-placeholder-image.png')

    // now load the images
    post.imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(await fetch(post.img).then(res => res.blob()))
  }
},
beforeDestroy() {
  // cleanup
  this.posts.forEach(({ imgUrl }) => {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(imgUrl)
  })
}
```

and in your template

```html
<a v-for="(post,index) in posts" :key="index">
  <img :src="post.imgUrl" >
</a>
```